# RestKit RKObjectMapping to CLLocation

Tags: ios, json, mapping, restkit, cllocation

I am using RestKit's Object Mapping to map JSON data to an object.
Is it possible to map the latitude and longitude JSON attributes to a `CLLocation` variable in my Objective-C class?

The JSON:

```
{ "items": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "latitude": "48.197186",
        "longitude": "16.267452"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "latitude": "48.199615",
        "longitude": "16.309645"
    }
]
```

}

The class it should be mapped to:

```
@interface ItemClass : NSObject    
  @property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *location;
@end
```

In the end I'd like to call `itemClassObj.location.longitude` getting me the value of the latitude from the JSON response.

I thought something like this would work, but it doesn't.

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ItemClass class]];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"latitude" toAttribute:@"location.latitude"];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"longitude" toAttribute:@"location.longitude"];
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a CLLocation you need both the latitude and the longitude at the same time.  Moreover, the coordinates for CLLocation (like CLLocationCoordinate2D) aren't NSNumbers, they're double floats, so it can jack up the key value compliance in mapping like this because floats aren't objects.

Most often, people will store a latitude and longitude in a class as NSNumbers and then build the CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate on demand after the class object is instantiated/populated.

What you *could* do, if you were so inclined, is utilize the willMapData: delegate method to snoop the data coming in, in order to manually populate a CLLocation ... but to me this is overkill and requires too much overhead.

---

**EDIT:** Adding this because comments don't format code property...

Or, you could put something like this in your object class implementation and interface...

```
@property (nonatomic,readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    CLLocationDegrees lat = [self.latitude doubleValue];
    CLLocationDegrees lon = [self.longitude doubleValue];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);
    if (NO == CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(coord))
        NSLog(@"Invalid Centroid: lat=%lf lon=%lf", lat, lon);
    return coord;
}
```

Comment: Is there a method that fires in my Model as soon as everything is mapped? Then I could simply assign the mapped lat & long values to CLLocationCoordinate...

Comment: Why not create a readonly property on your model that does this for you? You just call it up whenever you're ready to throw it on a map...  Since comments can't format code worth a damn, see my edits above.

Comment: Also, I think as far as a direct response to your post-mapping question, `objectMapperDidFinishMapping:`?

Comment: Hey thanks... Yes I implemented something similar to your approach this morning and it's working like a charm. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Good to hear, and I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 3):

RestKit has added a ValueTransformer specifically for CLLocation:

https://github.com/RestKit/RKCLLocationValueTransformer

Given the example JSON:

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "Blake Watters",
        "location": {
            "latitude": "40.708",
            "longitude": "74.012"
        }
    }
}
```

To map from the given JSON to a User object:

```
@interface User : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) CLLocation *location;
@end
```

Use the RKCLLocationValueTransformer:

```
#import "RKCLLocationValueTransformer.h"

RKObjectMapping *userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"name" ]];
RKAttributeMapping *attributeMapping = [RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"location" toKeyPath:@"location"];
attributeMapping.valueTransformer = [RKCLLocationValueTransformer locationValueTransformerWithLatitudeKey:@"latitude" longitudeKey:@"longitude"];
[userMapping addPropertyMapping:attributeMapping];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"user" statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
```